# How to get absolute server path of downloaded file

Tags: php, webserver, metadata

I have downloaded a file from a page with url `download.php?id=312`, which 'attaches' a file from the server.

Can I somehow find the absolute path to the file on the server, i.e., the real path - not just the URL from which I got the file?

The filename is 'hidden' since it's downloaded through the PHP file `download.php`, but can the file give a clue where the file was downloaded from, or is it completely hidden?

Comment: It is possible that it is completely hidden.  If you were in linux,  **wget http://1.1.1.1/download.php?id=312**  Might still work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in general, without access to the source code for (at least) download.php. The code could literally be taking the file from anywhere it had access to on the file system. Or it may be pulling the file from a database. Or it may even be generating the file on the fly, so the file may literally not exist except during the request.

Comment: But I know that is is an uploaded pdf file. Does the PDF file store any meta data about its original location?

Comment: Just because it's uploaded doesn't mean the file exists in the file system. It could be stored in a database or some other data store. In general, uploading a file would not modify that file in any way, so specifically would not change the contained metadata to reflect where it is stored.